# How to subset datatable based on (value of first row + X), by group

Tags: r, data.table

Say my datatable look like this:

```
> data=data.table(id=c('1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2'),value=c(10,20,30,60,80,20,40,55, 90, 100))
> data
    id value
 1:  1    10
 2:  1    20
 3:  1    30
 4:  1    60
 5:  1    80
 6:  2    20
 7:  2    40
 8:  2    55
 9:  2    90
10:  2   100
```

I want to subset this table, by id, by a specified range. In other words I would like to do something like this*:

```
data.subset<- data[, .SD[c(1,1+60)], by="id"]
```

where I want to select the first row, plus the sum of the first row's value and 60. The first row's value is different for each id.

I understand how to do this for the first row, and the Nth row. But I'm not sure how to do this for some static value (in this case 60).

My desired output is:

```
> data.subset
    id value
 1:  1    10
 2:  1    20
 3:  1    30
 4:  1    60
 6:  2    20
 7:  2    40
 8:  2    55
```

For id = 1: 10 + 60 = 70, thus select values in range of 10 - 70.

For id = 2: 20 + 60 = 80, thus select values in range of 20 - 80.

* as an example, i know this is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

```
data[, .SD[between(value, value[1], value[1] + 60, incbounds=T)], by="id"]

#   id value
#1:  1    10
#2:  1    20
#3:  1    30
#4:  1    60
#5:  2    20
#6:  2    40
#7:  2    55
```

Per @jazzurro's comment `between()` is more convenient.

Comment: You can use `between()` too. `data[, .SD[between(value, value[1], 60, incbounds = TRUE)], by = id]`